# Equality in distribution of random variables and their probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose we have two sequences of random variables $\{X_n(\theta)\}_{n\ge 1}$ and $\{Y_n(\theta)\}_{n\ge 1}$ and they are equal in distribution for all $n \ge 1$ and $\theta \in \Theta$ where $\Theta$ is, say, compact. Let us further assume that
$$\tag{1}\label{eq1}\mathbb{P}(\sup_{\theta\in\Theta} \vert Y_n(\theta) \vert > \epsilon) \to 0.$$
Can we claim that
$$\tag{2}\label{eq2}\mathbb{P}(\sup_{\theta\in\Theta} \vert X_n(\theta) \vert > \epsilon) \to 0.$$
My intuition is telling me yes, because if $X_n(\theta)$ and $Y_n(\theta)$ are equal in distribution, then
$$\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega: \sup_{\theta \in \Theta} \vert X_n(\theta; \omega) \vert > \epsilon\}) = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega: \sup_{\theta \in \Theta} \vert Y_n(\theta; \omega) \vert > \epsilon\})\to 0.$$
In fact, $\Theta$ needs not be compact. I want to claim \eqref{eq2} from \eqref{eq1} (provided that $X_n(\theta)$ is equal to $Y_n(\theta)$ in distribution for all $n\ge 1$, $\theta \in \Theta$). However, I am not sure if I can do that. If I can't, is there a counter example? If I can, is a proof required or is the implication simple enough that I can do without one?

Comment: The only thing you need to check is measurability of the events you are taking the probability of. This is similar to the issue of continuous paths of Brownian motion. If $\Theta$ is countable, then the sets are measurable, but if $\Theta$ is uncountable, they might not be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is correct with just the assumption that $X_n(\theta)$ and $Y_n(\theta)$ have the same distribution for all $n,\theta$.  Consider $\Theta = \mathbb{N}$, $\Omega = [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, $Y_n(k; \omega) = 1_{[0,\frac 1n]}(\omega)$ for all $k \in \Theta$.  Let $X_n(k;\omega) = 1_{\left[\frac{k-1}{n},\frac kn\right]}(\omega)$ for $k \le n$ and $X_n(k;\omega) = 1_{[0,\frac 1n]}(\omega)$ for $k > n$.  Then, for all $n \ge 1$ and $\theta \in \Theta$ we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y_n(\theta) = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_n(\theta) = 1) = \frac 1n
\end{align*}
so $X_n(\theta)$ and $Y_n(\theta)$ have the same distribution.  For any $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$, we have $\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_\theta Y_n(\theta) > \varepsilon \right) = \frac 1n \rightarrow 0$.  However, for all $\omega \in \Omega$ we have $\sup_{\theta}X(\theta;\omega) = 1$ so $\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_\theta X_n(\theta) > \varepsilon \right) = 1$, which clearly does not converge to $0$.

If we wanted to make $\Theta$ compact, I think we could apply the same example to the set $\hat \Theta := \{0,1,\frac 12, \frac 13, ... \}$.

To rule out something like this, you would need to say something about the *joint* (across $\theta$) distributions of $X_n(\theta)$ and $Y_n(\theta)$.